# Add an .app to a jailbroken device, and make it show up on the SpringBoard. (iOS 11.4.1)

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I created an app, and I want to copy it's Bundle via SSH to the iDevice and reload the springboard to see it.

The problem is I have no idea where to put the .app package.

iOS Version: 11.4.1

Can anyone assist with the simple yet so troublesome issue?

Comment: :self_facepalm: !

The answer, to whom it may concern, is to copy it to /Applications/ and run ```killall -9 SpringBoard```

Comment: You might also need to run `uicache`